# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord' or 'Python' error (in Atom)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

Yes, I'm writing a discord bot. I'm beginner and at the very beginning, but I get to the point.
I have my code here and there, and I really doubt the problem is with the code. (please note if it is) But when I try to run this code, I'm doing 2 commands.

First is python3 bot.py, when i'd try to run it, it simply says Python. I encountered the same in VS Code earlier, and all I did was adding python to environment variables, and it worked perfectly. But in Atom, it doesn't says anything except just the python word.
Second is just python bot.py, when I try it, I get another error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

same goes if I do import discord.py

Tried downloading many things, none worked.

Image with original code

[image]

Image with python3 error

[image]

Image with python error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are new to python programming language, I strongly recommend you to use some kind of virtual environment to separate installed packages of different projects on your system. you could use venv, pipenv, or other virtual enviroments.
[This tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#use-third-party-tools) will help you with virtual enviroments

Secondly from the [readthedocs page of the discord.py project](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html), you how see how you can install this module:

> You can get the library directly from PyPI:
>
> `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`
>
> If you are using Windows, then
> the following should be used instead:
>
> `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py`

if you read further you can find how to install inside a virtual environment.

Comment: i would have downloaded it, the problem is that py3 doesn't work as it's giving me the same error

Comment: @primarydestroyer1337 try testing python's shell interpreter, in command line type python and press enter, in the interpreter try importing disocrd. try this with python3, and py as well.

Comment: @primarydestroyer1337 also, I just found out that you are importing discord.py instead of discord, see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: yeah i changed the code to importing discord, i just thought that discord.py would make more sense, but i'd try what you just said and reach out

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the module in the terminal

```
pip3 install discord.py
```

Comment: was done yesterday, didn't help